# For what number of $n$ if we partition the edges of the complete graph $K_n$ into $4$ pieces then one of the pieces contains a $K_3$?

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

> For what number of $n$ if we partition the edges of the complete graph $K_n$ into $4$ pieces then one of the pieces contains a $K_3$?

Suppose I start with one vertex named $v$ then it have $n-1$ adjacent edges with other $n-1$ $\color{blue}{\text{vertices}}$. Now partition those $n-1$ edges into $4$ pieces with two or more edges in $\color{green}{\text{one partition}}$. If there is $\color{red}{\text{any edge}}$ among these $\color{blue}{\text{vertices}}$ (which is obviously exist because our graph is $K_n$) on that $\color{green}{\text{partition}}$, then there is a triangle mean $K_3$ graph. Put this $\color{red}{\text{edge}}$ in that $\color{green}{\text{partition}}$. Then one of the pieces contains a $K_3$. We can put rest edges randomly into those partition. I guess for $n\geq6$ do the work as the number of adjacent edges are more then $4$ which guarantee one partition contain two adjacent edges.

> But the answer is $n\geq R(6,6)$, where n is a Ramsey number $n=R(r,b)$, without any detail.

I was just lost how they get it from? It would be nice if anyone show me the right way.

Comment: If $n\ge R(R(3,3),R(3,3))$ and we colour the edges of $K_n$ in four colours darkblue, lightblue, darkred, lightred, then we produce a dark-ish $K_{R(3,3)}$ or a light-ish $K_{R(3,3)}$. At any rate, in this we find a kind-of-red $K_3$ or a kind-of-blue $K_3$. Hence $n\ge R(R(3,3),R(3,3))=R(6,6)$ is certainly *sufficient*. According to @Jorge 's answer, it is but not *necessary*.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to calculating the multichromatic Ramsey number $R(3,3,3,3)$. This article [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwii1uL2jeXvAhUIeawKHQgxDm4QFjAHegQIBhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fpii%2F0012365X7390174X%2Fpdf%3Fmd5%3D938e041125a6b7ad6c0f9471642cc987%26pid%3D1-s2.0-0012365X7390174X-main.pdf%26_valck%3D1&usg=AOvVaw2RKdcehZKJ-LFNnFEw-kRC) discusses it (although they use different notation). $R(6,6)$ is not equal to $R(3,3,3,3)$ as we know $R(6,6)\in [ 102,165]$ and $R(3,3,3,3)\in[50,65]$ (look at the article I linked).

Comment: Maybe the link [https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(73)90174-X](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(73)90174-X) is a bit better.

Comment: Thanks! The more the merrier I guess (within reason)

Comment: I see, I wasn't aware of multi-chromatic Ramsey number. Thanks @Jorge. I will look your suggested article and let you know what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

On p. 43 of the survey "Small Ramsey Numbers" by Stanisław Radziszowski

https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS1

it is stated that

> $$51\le R_4(3)=R(3,3,3,3)\le62.$$

The reference for the lower bound is F. R. K. Chung, On the Ramsey numbers $N(3,3,\dots,3;2)$, *Discrete Math.* 5 (1973), 317-321. The reference for the upper bound is S. Fettes, R. L. Kramer, and S. P. Radziszowski, An upper bound of $62$ on the classical Ramsey number $R(3,3,3,3)$, *Ars Combinatoria* 72 (2004), 41-63.