# Show that if $n \ge R(6,6)$ and we partition the edges of the complete graph $K_n$ into four pieces then one of the pieces contains a traingle.

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Show that if $n \ge R(6,6)$ and we partition the edges of the complete graph $K_n$ into four pieces then one of the pieces  contains a triangle.

How do I use the ramsey theorem to prove the above question?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4089265/33907

Comment: You don't have to use Ramsey's theorem. Just use the definition of $R(6,6)$ and the fact that $R(3,3)\le6$.